# returning float with all the numbers after period

Tags: python

Wanted to ask, why 
`5 / 100` 
returns
`0`
, but it works with 
`5 * 0.01`
, even though arithmetically both should return the same value?

even `float(5 / 100)` returns `0.0`

Comment: first - you are using python 2; so write 5.0/100; float() does not work because first you get 0 and then get float - 0.0

Comment: Acyually - just stop using python 2 - it's dead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`5/100` return `0` because you are dividing two integers, not floating point numbers. Division of any two integers will return an integer number.

Same reason for `float(5/100)`. In this case you are first dividing two integers and then converting its result, which is integer `0`, to floating point number.

If any of the number in the arithmetic operation is a floating point number, then the result would be also be a floating point number.
For example, `float(5)/100`. This will return `0.05` because you are dividing a floating point number, i.e. `float(5)`, by an integer `100`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using *Python 2.x*, because `5 / 100` returns `0.05` on *Python 3.x*

To achieve the behavior you want on *Python 2.x*, you need to inherit this functionality:

```
from __future__ import division
print 5 / 100 # Yields 0.05
```

If you only want to do this just one time and not modify the interpreter default behavior, you can just cast one of the operands to `float`

```
print 5 / float(100) # Yields 0.05
```